# Backup Exec 12.5 runs until another tape is inserted

Tags: backup, symantec

Any ideas why Backup Exec 12.5 would keep a job in the "running" state until a new tape is inserted (when it doesn't need to write anything to the new tape)?

We've got an LTO-3 drive (400/800GB), backing up 80GB of data.  The backup starts at 11PM and the last thing backed up (according to the job history) is around 12:45AM.  It will eject the tape, but keep the job in the "running" state.  As soon as I insert another tape, after about 5 seconds, the job completes.  I've cataloged the "new" tape, and nothing new was written to it today.  This doesn't seem to hurt anything, but it's annoying that the Job Monitor page doesn't accurately reflect the length of a backup and I have to drill into each backup's "History" to get this info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is there is an alert "Please remove the media from the drive" that hasn't been responded to.

Inserting a new tape probably makes it clear that you removed the tape.

You can respond to the alert or set a rule to automatically respond to this class of alerts.

Take a look at the alerts tab - Alert History subtab for an alert with a green circle/white question mark

Type: Attention Required
Category: Media Remove

I have mine set to automatically clear after 13 minutes but then only one backup a week (Full) automatically ejects for me. I have to manually eject my Differential tape.

To automatically clear that alert.

1. Tools - Alert Categories
2. Media Remove (blue square/white question mark)
3. Select Automatically clear alert after
4. Change the number of minutes, hours, or days
5. Click OK

Maybe you want it set to 1 minute?

Comment: Pretty sure that's it.  Thanks.  I'll confirm after tonight's backup, but those are the only alerts in the history, so you're likely right-on.